# @Parameters not working properly

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm working on **Selenium2 (Java)** with **testng 6.7** frame work. I'm using `@parameters` for getting the parameters from **testng.xml**. I have done everything in correct way.

Everything works perfectly. But some times it is not working. Simply all the test cases are skipped. If I removed the `@Parameters({"dsfsfdf}}`. It works well.

Can any one help me why this is not working some times.

Comment: No stacktrace even tests are skipped?

Answer (score 1):

this same  happened for me too. you can check this and make sure.

1) Check your testng.xml, and make sure your parameter "p" should be small in letter(It is case-sensitive).

2) Check your @Parameters values.

This will give your required output I think so, post me if it really works.